# Cannot create new conda environment with same python version as 'base'

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I wish to create new environment for a new project so that I can install various packages in it. And those packages will not then affect my base environment.
My base is at 3.6.6
I want my new environment should also be of same python version. But could not do it.

Here is what I did:

```
conda create -n mynewenv # you must specify python version... why?
conda create -n mynewenv python=3.6.6 # so as to make it exact of 'base'. No, you can not specify 3.6.6 but only upto 3.6
conda create -n mynewenv python=3.6 # in the list to install it showed 3.6.8...why? I want only 3.6.6
conda create -n mynewenv python # somewhere I read that just by giving 'python' picks up the 'base' version. But no...it picked 3.7...why?
```

Please suggest correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to dump only the Python build info from **base** into a requirements file, then use that for the new env creation.  This would ensure that the Python is literally the same one in **base**.

```
conda list -n base --export | grep "^python=" > base-py.txt
conda create -n mynewenv --file base-py.txt
```

Or if you want a one-liner that avoids the temporary file:

```
conda create -n mynewenv --file <(conda list -n base --export | grep "^python=")
```

Comment: Only the python version needs to be same as 'base'...rest of the packages would be different in the new env...

Comment: @Yogesh yes, that's exactly what this does.

Comment: base-py.txt stored "python==3.6.6=he025d50_0"  ..when tried to create new env with this it said Package Not Found in the current channels...should I add some specific channels before?

Comment: @Yogesh looks like [it's a Conda Forge build](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/files?version=3.6.6). If you add `-c conda-forge` flag to the create command, then it should work. Or you can [add Conda Forge permanently](https://conda-forge.org/#about).